Getting a file hosted in sharepoint into snowflake
I would like to automate the process of getting files hosted in sharepoint into a table in Snowflake. What is the best strategy to achieve this. I want to automate the process as well so that lets say every morning at said time the pipeline pulls fresh data from sharepoint into a table.

you can try to copy data from a SharePoint Online using Azure Data Factory and the Copy activity in an Azure Synapse pipeline, and then use the Snowflake connector in Azure Data Factory to load the data into a Snowflake table. You need to configure a connection to your Snowflake account and specify a target table.
